# python - stop the script when -1 is typed

Tags: python

The program must stop when the number `-1` was informed

```
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n <= -1:
        quit()
    else:
        print(n)
```

input

```
(0, 1, 5, -1)
```

exit

```
(0, 1, 5)
```

how can I do so that the `-1` is printed on the output?

Comment: Just remove the `else` clause and put the `print` before the `if`

Comment: Is it not doing that already? it stops when -1 is inputed

Comment: when printing it does not consider the -1 so only print the other values

Comment: Use `break` statement. There is no `quit()` builtin function in Python. you need to show the import or module reference; it's not clear which `quit()` function you're calling, it could be `pdb`, or `Qt` GUI, or ten other things...

Comment: Please see Python doc [4.4. `break` and `continue` Statements, and `else` Clauses on Loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=quit#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is print the -1 before the program quits.

In that case, you can do:

```py
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n <= -1:
        print(n)
        quit()
    else:
        print(n)
```

*But*, since the print is on both the `if` branch and the `else` branch, you can move it out of the branches completely, like so:

```py
while True:
    n = int(input())
    print(n)
    if n <= -1:
        quit()
```

This will result in the -1 being printed in the output (before ending the program). Note how you no longer need the `else`, because there isn't anything else you need to do if it's not <=-1.